# How to position a bootstrap button responsively?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've recently started learning CSS and Bootstrap. I added a bootstrap button to a page I've made but I can't get it to act responsively. Whenever I resize my window the button stays put. I think there's something wrong with my code but I can't get my head around it.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: url("header.jpg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:visited {
  background-color: orangered;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  outline: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 480px;
  left: 475px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Startup</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="startstyle.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h3>THE BIGGEST STARTUP EVENT OF THE YEAR</h3>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">FIND OUT MORE</button>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly would you like the botton to do, stretch, be centered?

Comment: I want the button to be centered with the specified top: 480px position.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

**I have modified Your code check this**

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Startup</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="startstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <h3>THE BIGGEST STARTUP EVENT OF THE YEAR</h3>
        <div class="row p-0 text-center">
        <div class="col-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">FIND OUT MORE</button>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
  body,html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-image:url("header.jpg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

h3{
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:visited{
    background-color: orangered;
    border-radius: 24px;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    outline: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.container{
    position: relative;    
}

button{
position:relative;
top: 480px;

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Didn't work. The button is not centered and changes its position when window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u r expecting check out my answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Startup</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="startstyle.css">
  <style>
  body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: url("header.jpg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

h3 {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:visited {
  background-color: orangered;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  outline: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 480px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>THE BIGGEST STARTUP EVENT OF THE YEAR</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">FIND OUT MORE</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't work. Button is not even centered at max window size.

Comment: on which side horizontally or vertically @Aditya

Comment: Horizontally @Amaresh S M